# Allow Wget to download only application type of PDF

Tags: linux, unix, web-crawler, wget

I am using wget on Window machine. i want only pdf file. if application/type is pdf . allow only to download

I am using this command

```
wget  --accept pdf www.google.com
```

it is downloading index page of google.

> Length: 19404 (19K) [text/html] Saving to:
>   `index.html@gfe_rd=cr&ei=5O8jVLycNuvA8gftoYGIBg'

i dont want to allow . if there is only pdf.

Any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Normally this would be

> wget --header='Accept: application/pdf' www.google.com

but google.com seems to ignore the Accept: header, so you may want to

> wget --debug --header='Accept: application/pdf' www.google.com 2>&1 | grep 'Content-Type: application/pdf'

and test the result of that command.

Comment: it is stil downloading html files

Comment: As I said Google ignores the header. It is your job to check the status of the command above and ignore the file if the status is not success. There is no other way.
For servers that correctly process the Accept header they will not send anything but PDF (if the PDF resource exists).